# Add style rule dialog box in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

Just noticed that Add Style rule dialogue box which showed up CSS-outline is missing in VS2012 or I am missing some changes made by MS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed on the MSDN forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/80538b67-a458-4140-8373-dabfebb2ba25).

> As far as I know that the Style menu has been moved from VS2012,
>   however, you can get the Build Style feature from the toolbar. Go to
>   View->Toolbars->Style Sheet.
>
> However, you still can't get the "Add Style Rule" option which is
>   available in VS2010. If you feel it is a very important feature to
>   you, you can consider submitting one feature request on the Microsoft
>   UserVoice site here:
>   http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks Josh just submitted the request.